# Background of ul list is white. How to remove background?

Tags: html, css

I've tried this, but I still see a white background on the ul

```
*{
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}
```

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <h1 class="title">PARALLEX</h1>
    <style>.main.img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.title{
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 450%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 12.5%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 1.25em;
}

li, a, button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
*{
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}
nav {
  order: 1;
}
.nav_links {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
.nav_links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.nav_links li a:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav_links">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <img class="main img" src="mountains.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the code you posted, the background-color is NOT white. If you add a black background to `body` or whatever wrapper, the `nav` / `ul` is displayed with white text on black background. (If you don't add anything, you don't see anything, since everything is white)

Comment: If I'm correct in interpreting your question you actually want the `ul` to be on top of image you are trying to make into a background image? Maybe update your wording to reflect that, because everyone is thinking you want no background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is not behind the `ul` because in the HTML the image comes after the `ul` so without further instruction the image renders after the list.

Add a left and top value to place your image in the top corner:

```
.main.img {
  height: 100vh; // "viewport height" seems more appropriate than % in this case
  width:100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1; // negative puts it behind anything with the default value, so you don't need to define the z-index of every single element
}
```

`ul` does not have a background by default, so you can remove that block of css: `*{`...

Answer (score 2):

Can you clarify your issue? When I open your code my background is white but if I change the body elements background to red then the page turns red.

For example this is what I see when body is purple. I don't have the image file so that's why the white line is there.
[image]

Also why is your H1 element in the Head? It should be in the body

```
  <body>
    <h1 class="title">PARALLEX</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav_links">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <img class="main img" src="mountains.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
```